# How to change height of Bottom Tab Navigator in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-bottom-tab

I am trying to change height of my bottom tab navigator bar in React Native. I've tried some answers from this [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57201508/react-navigation-increase-height-of-the-bottom-tab-navigation) but nothing seems to work. Please help.

My code:

```
export default function AppTabs({ logged }) {
  const Tabs = createBottomTabNavigator();

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <Tabs.Navigator
          screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
            tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color, size }) => {
              const current_color = focused ? COLORS.white : COLORS.lightGrey;

              if (route.name === "Home") {
                return <Foundation name="home" size={28} color={current_color}/>
              } else if (route.name === "Search") {
                return <Ionicons name="search" size={28} color={current_color} />
              } else if (route.name === "Library") {
                return <MaterialCommunityIcons name="bookshelf" size={28} color={current_color} />
              }
            },
            header: () => null,
            tabBarActiveBackgroundColor: COLORS.darkGgrey,
            tabBarInactiveBackgroundColor: COLORS.darkGgrey,
            tabBarActiveTintColor: COLORS.white,
            tabBarInactiveTintColor: COLORS.lightGrey
          })}
        >
          <Tabs.Screen name="Home" component={Home}/>
          <Tabs.Screen name="Search" component={Search}/>
          <Tabs.Screen name="Library" component={Library}/>
        </Tabs.Navigator>
        <PlayerBar track_name="Heart Attack" artist="Dave"/>
      </SafeAreaView>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Comment: See this discussion on stack to achive your goal [BottomTabNavigator Height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57201508/react-navigation-increase-height-of-the-bottom-tab-navigation)

Comment: @64Bit1990 OP has always said this link didn't work for him in starting of question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can try this

```
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

export const TabNavigation = () => {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
      tabBarStyle: {height: 60},
    }}>
    ...
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
};
```